# How it is possible to create object for HttpServletRequest Interface?

Tags: java, object, servlets, interface

How it is possible to create object for `HttpServletRequest` Interface?

`HttpServletRequest` is an interface, but still servlet container can create object of the same. How? Why?

Comment: Did you never wonder how `List`, `Map`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, etc work? It are all also interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The servlet container has a class implementing this interface, and instantiates an object of this class. Just like when you do

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

`List` is an interface, and you instantiate `ArrayList`, which is a class implementing `List`.

The servlet container does something like the following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = new TomcatHttpServletRequestImpl();
```

This is the basis of OO and polymorphism.